# Beep sound after pressing enter too many times

Tags: command-line, sound

So I pressed enter in terminal repeatedly and then computer started beeping. But it beeps when I turn music on or any video where is sound. How can I turn it off, it's annoying?..

Answer (score 1):

Changed Audio hardwares profile (settings) back and forth and that sound disappeared. It seems it was bugged somehow.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Go to **System Settings**

2 - Click on **Sound**

3 - Click on the **Sound Effects** tab

4 - Switch it to **Off**

[image: Sound Settings]

Comment: Alert was already turned off for me, don't know why it started beeping when other sound was outputted.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably activated the speaker driver that produce beeps. To disable it, run the following command:

```
sudo modprobe -r pcspkr
```

To disable it permanently, be sure that you have the following line in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file:

```
blacklist pcspkr
```